# External style sheet with multiple linked html

Tags: html, css

Is it possible to have different multiple body backgrounds but only using 1 image depending on what html file is accessed?

To clarify i have 1 external style sheet but i have 3 html files each accessing the external style sheet what i want to do is have 3 different body background image for each html file. What would be the proper way of doing this?

```
body {
background-image: url("backGroundImage1.jpg");
background-repeat: no-repeat;
background-position: center top;
background-size: cover;
background-attachment: fixed; }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using `Id` or `class` would be the best way to achieve what you are looking for.

You need to add the below CSS to your main stylesheet file and based on your requirements and pages, you can add them to your `<body>` with either `ID's` or `Classes`.

**For instance, using with ID**

```
body#One {
background-image: url("backGroundImage1.jpg");
background-repeat: no-repeat;
background-position: center top;
background-size: cover;
background-attachment: fixed; }

body#two {
background-image: url("backGroundImage2.jpg");
background-repeat: no-repeat;
background-position: center top;
background-size: cover;
background-attachment: fixed; }

body#three {
background-image: url("backGroundImage3.jpg");
background-repeat: no-repeat;
background-position: center top;
background-size: cover;
background-attachment: fixed; }
```

**The HTML:**

`<body id="One">...</body>` or
`<body id="two">...</body>` or
`<body id="three">...</body>` for your pages.

**For instance, using with Class**

```
body.One {
background-image: url("backGroundImage1.jpg");
background-repeat: no-repeat;
background-position: center top;
background-size: cover;
background-attachment: fixed; }

body.two {
background-image: url("backGroundImage2.jpg");
background-repeat: no-repeat;
background-position: center top;
background-size: cover;
background-attachment: fixed; }

body.three {
background-image: url("backGroundImage3.jpg");
background-repeat: no-repeat;
background-position: center top;
background-size: cover;
background-attachment: fixed; }
```

**The HTML:**

`<body class="One">...</body>` or
`<body class="two">...</body>` or
`<body class="three">...</body>` for your pages.

You can insert them on these pages as per your requirements.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks! It was actually this simple haha

Answer (score -1):

Hope it helps

```css
/* For all pages */
body {
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: center top;
    background-size: cover;
    background-attachment: fixed;
}

/*first page*/
body.first {
    background-image: url("backGroundImage1.jpg");
}
/*second page*/
body.second {
    background-image: url("backGroundImage2.jpg");
}
/*third page*/
body.third {
    background-image: url("backGroundImage3.jpg");
}
```